# Interest Calculator

Tags: java

Problem with my code for calculator - output values not correct
Here is my code, any response would be appreciated.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Savings {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);

//ask for initial amount
        System.out.print("What is the initial savings amount? ");

        double initialAmount = console.nextDouble();

// ask for number of months
        System.out.print("What is the number of months to save? ");

        int months = console.nextInt();

//ask for interest rate
        System.out.print("What is the annual interest rate? ");

        double interestRate = console.nextDouble();

//calculate total



        double monthlyInterest = ((interestRate/100)*(1/12));

        double number1 = (monthlyInterest + 1);

        double number2 = Math.pow(number1, months);

        double total = (initialAmount*number2);


        System.out.println("$" + initialAmount + ", saved for " + months + " months at " + interestRate + "% will be valued at $" + total);

        console.close();
    }
}
```

final value ends up being the same value as initial

Comment: give us an example to input and output and expected output please

Comment: example input is 25000 and output is 25530.31 with 24 months and 1.05 as time and interest respectively

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change this:

```
double monthlyInterest = ((interestRate/100)*(1/12));
```

to

```
double monthlyInterest = (interestRate / 100) * (1.0 / 12.0);
```

You're trying to do integer division in floating-point context, so in `monthlyInterest` you are essentially multiplying `interestRate / 100` with 0.

Answer (score 2):

Add `d` with the numbers to convert them into double and keep the decimal value, this way -

```
double monthlyInterest = ((interestRate/100d)*(1/12d));
```

If you do `1/12` with integers, the output will be `0`, but with `1/12d` it will be `0.08333333333333333`

---

Also, you can get rid of the extra parenthesis -

```
double monthlyInterest = (interestRate/100d)*(1/12d);
...
double number1 = monthlyInterest + 1;
...
double total = initialAmount * number2;
```